# Loading an Inkbox Signature, stored as an array from SQLserverCE

Tags: c#, vb.net, compact-framework, .net

I am developing a smart application in C# using CF 3.5 which requires the ability to capture signatures.

To implement this I am using Resco's InkBox control. To save and load the images I have attempted to convert the VB source code provided into C#. [Resco InkBox source code](http://www.resco.net/developer/support/tutorials.aspx?p=WindowsMobile&comp=inkbox#2)

The application saves the signature without any issues however, when I try to load the file from the database I get an **Invalid Cast Exception** on the following line of code;

```
 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.ToByte(dr["Signature"]));
```

Which I converted from the following VB code.

```
 New System.IO.MemoryStream(CType(myReader("Signature"), Byte()))
```

I have tested the VB code provided and it works perfectly. Is anyone able to offer me any suggestions to solve this issue because I am absolutely stumped. All help will be greatly apprieciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast to a byte *array*

```
var stream = new MemoryStream((byte[])dr["Signature"]);
```